# Memory usage in NodeJS zlib stream

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

I may be wrong but this is how I understand Node's `createGzip()`:

- I can `stream.write()` - it accumulates data in the stream,
- the "compression" process happens only upon calling `stream.end()` - then Gzip does it's magic based on what is in the stream and unloads everything.

This requires pretty big amount of memory because stream has to hold everything until I call `end()`.

Can I somehow "train" gzip on small amount of data (I mean to train it how to compress data. My data has similar patterns throughout entire dataset) and then just stream everything through it without waiting for `stream.end()`?

I want to compress ~100GB of data and stream just won't be able to accumulate that much due to runtime's memory limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Node's zlib implementation works like described in a post. It accumulates entire data in the buffer before calling `end()`.

One solution is to use `pako` package. This is custom zlib wrapper.

It doesn't support streams out of the box but you can overwrite methods `onData()` and turn it into stream pretty easily. You can then achieve true streaming compression.